# Logstash Codec - Avro Schema Registry: avro_schema_registry fails due to undefined local variable or method `esponse'

Tags: ruby, apache-kafka, logstash, jruby, confluent-schema-registry

I have a Logstash conf which reads from a Kafka topic in json format, it uses avro_schema_registry to serialize output to avro.
Here is the conf file:

```
input {
  kafka{
    group_id => "test_group"
    topics => ["logs_json"]
    bootstrap_servers => "server2:9094, server1:9094, server3:9094"
    codec => "json"
    consumer_threads => 1
  }
}

output {
  kafka {
    codec => avro_schema_registry {
      endpoint => "http://host_schema_registry:port"
      schema_id  => 1
    }
    value_serializer => "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer"
    bootstrap_servers => "server1:9094, server1:9094, server1:9094"
    topic_id => "logs_avro"
  }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
org.jruby.exceptions.NameError: (NameError) undefined local variable or method `esponse' for #<SchemaRegistry::Client:0x3c5ad39>
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.schema_registry_minus_0_dot_1_dot_0.lib.schema_registry.client.request(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/schema_registry-0.1.0/lib/schema_registry/cli
ent.rb:127) ~[?:?]
        at uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.start(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http.rb:914) ~[?:?]
        at uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.start(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http.rb:609) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.schema_registry_minus_0_dot_1_dot_0.lib.schema_registry.client.request(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/schema_registry-0.1.0/lib/schema_registry/cli
ent.rb:101) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.schema_registry_minus_0_dot_1_dot_0.lib.schema_registry.client.schema(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/schema_registry-0.1.0/lib/schema_registry/clie
nt.rb:40) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_codec_minus_avro_schema_registry_minus_1_dot_1_dot_1.lib.logstash.codecs.avro_schema_registry.get_schema(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/g
ems/logstash-codec-avro_schema_registry-1.1.1/lib/logstash/codecs/avro_schema_registry.rb:158) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_codec_minus_avro_schema_registry_minus_1_dot_1_dot_1.lib.logstash.codecs.avro_schema_registry.encode(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/
logstash-codec-avro_schema_registry-1.1.1/lib/logstash/codecs/avro_schema_registry.rb:246) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_integration_minus_kafka_minus_10_dot_0_dot_0_minus_java.lib.logstash.outputs.kafka.multi_receive(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logs
tash-integration-kafka-10.0.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/kafka.rb:219) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1800) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.8.0.jar:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_integration_minus_kafka_minus_10_dot_0_dot_0_minus_java.lib.logstash.outputs.kafka.multi_receive(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logs
tash-integration-kafka-10.0.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/kafka.rb:217) ~[?:?]
        at org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.OutputStrategyExt$AbstractOutputStrategyExt.multi_receive(org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/OutputStrategyExt.java:118) ~[logstash-core.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.multi_receive(org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.java:101) ~[logstash-core.jar:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.start_workers(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:262) ~[?:?]
[2020-02-11T13:11:41,720][ERROR][org.logstash.execution.WorkerLoop][main] Exception in pipelineworker, the pipeline stopped processing new events, please check your filter configuration and restart Logstash.
```

Comment: How did you install that codec?

Comment: @cricket_007 
-- sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-codec-avro_schema_registry

Comment: Can you open `/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/schema_registry-0.1.0/lib/schema_registry/client.rb` and see line 127? I assume `esponse` is `response`... And the latest version is 1.1.1, not 0.1.0 - https://github.com/revpoint/logstash-codec-avro_schema_registry#v111

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007
The version for logstash-codec-avro_schema_registry is 1.1.1, but for schema registry itself is 0.1.0 which is another package:
https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry
Thanks for your hints, now the error changed after fixing 'esponse'
I keep this post updated

Comment: Even there, the latest version is 5.3.2... I think you meant this one https://github.com/wvanbergen/schema_registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging more the code, I understood the Internal Server error was due to a line in client.rb to set 'Accept' in the GET request header.

```
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/schema_registry-0.1.0/lib/schema_registry/client.rb:112
        request['Accept'] = "application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json"
```

by either commenting or changing the value to request['Accept'] = "application/json", the GET request went through successfully.

Comment: That's the incorrect header according to the API spec for the Registry, though

Comment: which one is incorrect?
this one? request['Accept'] = "application/json"

Comment: Yeah, the values are just strings. `vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json` is the documented one by Confluent

Comment: I see what you mean
but again some lines after Content-Type is different than documentation: https://github.com/wvanbergen/schema_registry/blob/master/lib/schema_registry/client.rb in line 114
          request['Content-Type'] = "application/json"

Answer (score 0):

That codec (was) broken

Refer issue - https://github.com/wvanbergen/schema_registry/issues/5

---

There is no reason to serialize JSON to Avro, **then** insert into Elasticsearch anyway since Elasticsearch stores JSON, but if you did want to do that, I'd suggest using Confluent's Elasticsearch Kafka Connector instead.

If you're not even using Elasticsearch, I don't think Logstash should really be used.

KSQL supports what you're trying to do - https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/changing-data-serialization-format-json-avro/

Comment: I need to have the avro format messages in the Kafka topic (not elastic)
initially I did this conversion with nifi, but it's too much overhead just for the conversion, so I thought I can use this Codec

Comment: Well, seems that issue got fixed now that I tagged the developer... Maybe try reinstalling your codec and see what happens. Then again, Kafka Connect is fully tested by Confluent to support Avro and Elasticsearch. But your logstash flow clearly shows consuming as JSON and trying to output to Kafka as Avro, so I'd suggest reading this https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/changing-data-serialization-format-json-avro/