# Dump Elasticsearch documents into avro file using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, avro, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I want to store elasticsearch query results into avro files using logstash..As far as I know there file output logstash plugin which by default stores JSON documents.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-file.html

[image]

after going through logstash documentation,I could see there avro codec plugin which can be used to serialize logstash events(i.e. elasticSearch query) but looks like it doesn't support writing data into avro files

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-avro.html

[image]

Can anyone please help if there is any utility/logstash plugin available to dump JSON documents into avro format?

Appreciate your help. thank you

Comment: not sure if any of these two links help 1. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-figure-out-how-to-translate-from-json-to-avro-using-logstash/125464   2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60175223/logstash-codec-avro-schema-registry-avro-schema-registry-fails-due-to-undefin

Comment: @JBone no it didn't